# How do I get the authenticated user from Firebase Firestore 2nd Gen onDocumentData trigger?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How can determine the authenticated user who made the change within a Firestore **2nd gen trigger**?

The 1st gen `onUpdate` trigger provides a change object & a context object where you can get the auth. The equivalent 2nd gen `onDocumentUpdated` instead only provides an event object which doesn't appear to include the `auth` user.

1st gen

```
export const onUserUpdate = Firestore
    .document("users/{userId}")
    .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
        const before = change.data.before.data();
        const after = change.data.after.data();

        // Access the authenticated user information
        const user = context.auth;

        if (user) {
            console.log("Authenticated user ID:", user.uid);
            console.log("Authenticated user email:", user.token.email);
            console.log("Authenticated user name:", user.token.name);
            // You can access more user properties as needed
        } else {
            console.log("No authenticated user information available.");
        }
});
```

2nd gen

```
exports.onUserUpdate = onDocumentUpdated("user/{userId}", async (event) => {
    const before = event.data.before.data();
    const after = event.data.after.data();

    // how do I get auth?

    
});
```

```
event: FirestoreEvent<Change<QueryDocumentSnapshot>
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The 1st gen onUpdate trigger provides a change object & a context object where you can get the auth.

Actually, you *can't* get the user from that v1 context.  See:

- [Getting the user id from a Firestore Trigger in Cloud Functions for Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912161/getting-the-user-id-from-a-firestore-trigger-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase)
- [Does the firebase cloud functions context.auth field work for firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68800305/does-the-firebase-cloud-functions-context-auth-field-work-for-firestore)
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/300#issuecomment-611814916

And you *still* can't with v2 triggers.

You are welcome to send your feedback to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) about this, but I doubt anything will change soon as it's been over 5 years of people asking for this.

Answer (score 0):

While doug is correct with the Firebase API and the likeliness of any changes
I suggest providing a `context` or `operation` field to the document that contains all the essential data you need. with this, you can check the document data on this path field, and enforce it with security rules.

for example:
`event.data.after.data().context` should contain the new user who made the changes
while
`event.data.before.data().context` would contain information about the previous user

and due to the way firebase handles triggers, these should fire incrementally, best used with transactions but not required if you use security rules correctly. this can be further enhanced with additional fields to monitor updates and other rate limiting properties that you can validate with security rules.